# kafka.common.KafkaStorageException: I/O exception in append to log

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I get some big problems of kafka，when I shutdown my consumer application then change a groupId and restart it，my kafka brokers will stop working， this is the stack trace I get

```
[2016-07-11 17:02:47,314] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Loading offsets and group metadata from [__consumer_offsets,0] (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
[2016-07-11 17:02:47,955] FATAL [Replica Manager on Broker 0]: Halting due to unrecoverable I/O error while handling produce request:  (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
kafka.common.KafkaStorageException: I/O exception in append to log '__consumer_offsets-38'
        at kafka.log.Log.append(Log.scala:318)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$9.apply(Partition.scala:442)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$9.apply(Partition.scala:428)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:262)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inReadLock(CoreUtils.scala:268)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition.appendMessagesToLeader(Partition.scala:428)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager$$anonfun$appendToLocalLog$2.apply(ReplicaManager.scala:401)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager$$anonfun$appendToLocalLog$2.apply(ReplicaManager.scala:386)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:109)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.appendToLocalLog(ReplicaManager.scala:386)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.appendMessages(ReplicaManager.scala:322)
        at kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager.store(GroupMetadataManager.scala:228)
        at kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator$$anonfun$handleCommitOffsets$9.apply(GroupCoordinator.scala:429)
        at kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator$$anonfun$handleCommitOffsets$9.apply(GroupCoordinator.scala:429)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator.handleCommitOffsets(GroupCoordinator.scala:429)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleOffsetCommitRequest(KafkaApis.scala:280)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:76)
        at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:60)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/kafka-logs/__consumer_offsets-38/00000000000000000000.index (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
        at kafka.log.OffsetIndex$$anonfun$resize$1.apply(OffsetIndex.scala:277)
        at kafka.log.OffsetIndex$$anonfun$resize$1.apply(OffsetIndex.scala:276)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:262)
        at kafka.log.OffsetIndex.resize(OffsetIndex.scala:276)
        at kafka.log.OffsetIndex$$anonfun$trimToValidSize$1.apply$mcV$sp(OffsetIndex.scala:265)
        at kafka.log.OffsetIndex$$anonfun$trimToValidSize$1.apply(OffsetIndex.scala:265)
        at kafka.log.OffsetIndex$$anonfun$trimToValidSize$1.apply(OffsetIndex.scala:265)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:262)
        at kafka.log.OffsetIndex.trimToValidSize(OffsetIndex.scala:264)
```

Comment: Check whether your have sufficient disk space using `df -h ` command

Comment: /dev/vda1        40G  7.2G   31G   20% / I forget to say my two brokers are in the same server using two ports. 10.45.33.195:9092 and 10.45.33.195:9093

Comment: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/kafka-logs/__consumer_offsets-38/00000000000000000000.index (No such file or directory). Your broker stores the metadat in /tmp/kafka-logs folder. You should check whether this folder is still existed or not?

Comment: I use a new groupid to consume the messages,so I think the offset must be newly created and the offset file should be created by broker automatically.I suppose the broker failed to create the  directory "/__consumer_offsets-38" and the file "00000000000000000000.index"

Comment: since you have two brokers in the same server, do you config them to have different log directory?  otherwise I think it may have a impact to offset topic creation.

Comment: I use two  log directories "log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs" in the config file "server.pro" and "log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-1" in the config file "server-1.pro". start the two brokers like this:
kafka-server-start.sh ../config/server-1.properties
kafka-server-start.sh ../config/server.properties

Comment: @ericzhao I also got this problem, how did you fix it?

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwal I just set the log file to another directory

Comment: @ericzhao Thanks for the reply, I ended up being cleaning up and restarting the kafka cluster. After that never faced the issue again yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your /tmp is automatically cleaned up i.e. systemd-tmpfiles.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-tmpfiles.html

Comment: yeah,I guess so